# Data Model for Stock quantity

Tags: stock, datamodel, product-quantity

I would like to ask you about how to design a data model for books stock quantities. I tried to figure it out, but I finished with cartesian product, and for 300 books and for few years the stock fact table was a really huge. What is important, this solution could provide me an option I can see the stock quantities to specific date or period.

I searched a while and I also tried a read The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 1, but none of this help me too much.

But I think my solution is not right because libraries could have millions of books.

---

For start, there is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0_KaSs1h) example.

Purchases fact table: What book was purchase to library store

| purchase_key | date_key | book_key | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20231101 | 1 | 900,0 |
| 2 | 20231201 | 2 | 750,0 |

Orders fact table: What book was sold to customer

| order_key | date_key | book_key | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20240101 | 1 | 1080,0 |
| 2 | 20240101 | 2 | 900,0 |

Books dimension: Exact book exemplars

| book_key | book |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Dates dimension

| date_key | period_key |
| --- | --- |
| 20231101 | 202311 |
| 20231201 | 202312 |
| 20240101 | 202401 |

With the created view with cartesian product and the last select below I can let the report user filter the whole model.

```
select
  t1.period_key,
  t1.book,
  max(t1.delta)
from (
select 
  s.date_key,
  d.period_key,
  b.book,
  s.buys,
  s.sells,
  s.cum_buys,
  s.cum_sells,
  s.delta
from stocks s
  left join dates d on (d.date_key=s.date_key)
  left join books b on (b.book_key=s.book_key)
) t1
group by
  t1.period_key,
  t1.book
;
```

What is important, the user knows, that for `period=202312` there is still 1 quantity of `A` book on the stock. This book was bought `202311`.

| period_key | book | max(t1.delta) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202311 | A | 1 |
| 202311 | B | 0 |
| 202312 | A | 1 |
| 202312 | B | 1 |
| 202401 | A | 0 |
| 202401 | B | 0 |

| period_key | book | max(t1.delta) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202312 | A | 1 |
| 202312 | B | 1 |

But without the cartesian product a with filter above, the user would not see the purchases before.

---

I would like to thank you all in advance for your constructive advices

Best regards
Ondrej

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text - appropriately formatted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Hello, I edited the question, I apologize, Ondrej